# Какой лучше всего выбрать SSL сертификат?

Tags: ssl

Всем доброго времени суток! Столкнулись с таким вопросом выбора более оптимального варианта SSL сертификата для нашего сайта. Нам необходим SSL сертификат который будет работать на неограниченном количестве сайтов созданных внутри нашей системы. Такой вопрос что это за вид сертификата, какая у него примерная стоимости на рынке?

Answer (score 1):

[LetsEncypt's](https://letsencrypt.org) wildcard certificate. $0.